# ssh: relocation error: ssh: symbol EVP_enc_null, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, ssh, openssl

I have written a bash script that uses SCP to copy files to another server on the same LAN.

Eg.
    scp /opt/alfresco_associated/tomcat/temp/Alfresco/_source_4939853286195544661.tiff ocruser@10.16.0.6:/opt/ocr/data/temp/eng_119045725.tiff

If I execute this script directly using the terminal, it works without error. If I call it from a Java class running on Apache Tomcat, I get the below error message:

/usr/bin/ssh: relocation error: /usr/bin/ssh: symbol EVP_enc_null, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference
lost connection

Both source and target machines are running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS Server.

I have tried:
apt update
apt upgrade

Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.59
Server built:   Jan 28 2015 15:51:10 UTC
Server number:  7.0.59.0
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     4.4.0-64-generic
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.8.0_65-b17
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation

OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016

Comment: This might be an issue with the environment variables. They contain paths where the dynamic linker will search for shared libraries (such as `libcrypto.so.1.0.0). Make sure you Java invocation sets the same environment variables as your bash session does. An excerpt of the Java code issuing the command would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks. So it seems that Tomcat is using its own set of libraries, including libssl.so.1.0.0. This appears to be different from the OpenSSL 1.0.2g installed on the system. I commented out the line in tomcat's "setenv.sh" that included the custom libraries, and restarted tomcat. The error still persists. Is there a way to check, on runtime, what version of OpenSSL is Tomcat loading?

Answer (score 3):

I have fixed this by adding the below line to the top of my Bash script:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=""
```

This resets the environment variable that Tomcat is setting to point to custom libraries. For the session of the script, the default libraries are called.